# How do you remove the blue outline/border around everything on windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, display-settings

[image: screenshot showing blue border]

As you can see above, there is a blue border/focus/highlight or whatever you want to call it around the application. It also effects things like textboxes, buttons, and overall the border goes around everything.

I'd like to remove that blue border, regardless of what color it is.

Please don't say to turn off narrator, because that's not the issue I'm talking about. It's the color around the application.

Edit: I'm not trying to change the color. Im trying to make it borderless. Like transparent.

Answer (score 1):

i fixed it by going to settings --- personalization --- themes and selecting a windows 10 theme it immediately changed from thick to normal.  from there i could reselect my background and colour i wanted, hope that helps.